# Requests not routed through CloudFlare

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I have my domain example.com on CloudFlare and a subdomain, fo.example.com, delegated to another name server.

This is the setting on CloudFlare

A www.example.com 1.2.3.4

CNAME test www.example.com

CNAME test2 www.google.com

CNAME test3 fo.example.com

plus the NS for fo. All the above have the orange icon, i.e. requests should go through CloudFlare.

and this is the setting on the other nameserver

A fo.example.com 5.6.7.8

Now, when I traceroute www.example.com, test.example.com and test2.example.com I can see that it goes through CloudFlare but when I traceroute test3.example.com it goes direct exactly as I traceroute fo.example.com. This looks incorrect to me, why requests to a CNAME pointing to an extrenal domain (google.com) goes through cloudflare and the one pointing to a delegated subdomain does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudFlare supports answer:

> That's not possible, no way around it either. I've tried.
>   Unfortunately our current system doesn't allow this. This has been a
>   feature request for awhile, it will get added eventually, but no ETA
>   as of right now, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to look at without knowing the actual subdomain in question. There are some records that can't be proxied (pointing to other CDNs, for example, does create DNS lookup issues in some cases).

Comment: I set up a test domain: sollecitopagamento.it
So, fo.sollecitopagamento.it is direct while test3.sollecitopagamento.it should go through CloudFlare

Comment: The way you have things set relative to DNS is really strange. You have fo pointing to a NS record, which we can't proxy.

A typical setup would generally look like:

CNAME fo is an alias of sollecitopagamento.it

Comment: My goal is to have requests routed through CloudFlare first and then to a dns failover (in this case "fo" stands for failover and should be hosted with Route53). Any suggestions?